# rpmbuild spec enable configure build file

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I am using rpmbuild for util-linux.

This command works for me:

```
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/util-linux.spec
```

In the file util-linux-2.23.2.tar.xz  there is a file with the name configure and this file has properties that can be activated like

```
  --disable-eject         do not build eject
  --disable-agetty        do not build agetty
  --disable-cramfs        do not build fsck.cramfs, mkfs.cramfs
  --disable-bfs           do not build mkfs.bfs
  --disable-fdformat      do not build fdformat
  --disable-hwclock       do not build hwclock
  --disable-wdctl         do not build wdctl
  --disable-switch_root   do not build switch_root
  --disable-pivot_root    do not build pivot_root
  --enable-elvtune        build elvtune (only works with 2.2 and 2.4 kernels)
  --enable-tunelp         build tunelp
  --disable-kill          do not build kill
  --enable-last           build last
  --disable-utmpdump      do not build utmpdump
  --enable-line           build line
  --enable-mesg           build mesg
  --disable-raw           do not build raw
  --disable-rename        do not build rename
  --enable-reset          build reset
  --enable-vipw           build vipw
  --enable-newgrp         build newgrp
```

How to enable or disable any one in my command `rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/util-linux.spec`?

Answer (score 2):

Fedora's spec file for util-linux has this section:

```
%configure \
    --with-systemdsystemunitdir=%{_unitdir} \
    --disable-silent-rules \
    --disable-bfs \
    --disable-pg \
    --enable-chfn-chsh \
    --enable-usrdir-path \
    --enable-write \
    --disable-raw \
    --enable-hardlink \
    --enable-fdformat \
    --enable-asciidoc \
    --with-python=%{pyver} \
    --with-systemd \
    --with-udev \
    --with-selinux \
    --with-audit \
    --with-utempter \
    --disable-makeinstall-chown \
%ifarch s390 s390x
    --disable-hwclock \
    --disable-fdformat
%endif
```

I guess it's quite easy to figure out how to add/remove the options you're interested in.

Comment: i have centos 7 and i have this error error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /usr/bin/newgrp
   /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/newgrp
   /usr/share/man/man1/newgrp.1.gz

Comment: util-linux-2.23.2 is a Fedora 19 / CentOS 7 version → `util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7.src.rpm`  https://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/os/Source/SPackages/util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7.src.rpm ..... which has the updated file `util-linux.spec` : Edit to your requirements. ( The file inside the source is considered a template   util-linux.spec ).